# Best time of year to scuba dive in Belize/Honduras

Tags: diving, central-america, weather-and-climate, honduras, belize

I can't seem to find any information on *when* the best time of year to go scuba diving in Belize or Honduras, only that it's a great place to scuba dive. Does anyone happen to know?

**Update:** Yes, I am PADI certified. I don't know if being SSI certified makes a difference though. I would call myself a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a certified diver (Are you?.. I guessed you are because you asked for diving not getting diving lessons) you usually know to find the information about dive sites in www.padi.com website firstly. Then you can search more by giving some key words to the search engines and complete it.

[About Belize](http://www.padi.com/scuba/scuba-diving-trips/scuba-diving-resort-vacations/belize2/):

Dive Season: **Year-round**. Whale sharks sightings are virtually guaranteed from April to June along the southern barrier reef.

[About Honduras](http://www.padi.com/scuba/scuba-diving-trips/scuba-diving-resort-vacations/honduras/)

Dive Season: **All year**

There is not a best time for diving or in the other word it depends on your purpose, the kind of accommodations which you expect, the kind of species and sea life you want to see under the water and surely not all species are visible whole around the year, your free time and the weather condition that you feel more comfortable to dive. You can find all them in those two pages and select your best time according to your own favorite imagination of a favorite dive time.

Comment: There are definitely better and worse times.  If you can address what you wish to see, that can help determine your season.  There's also this minor factor called HURRICANE SEASON that puts a damper on diving.  Generally peak season runs April - June because of the whale sharks.

Comment: @PersianCat Well, I was afraid if I went during the rainy season that it would be a bad idea. I wouldn't want to be out in the Blue Hole while a storm approached and we were hours from shore. On the other hand, I had *heard* that diving during the rain was actually ideal, though I couldn't find anything reputable to back this.